# IPython: load extension automatically upon start

Tags: ipython

In IPython, I can load a custom extension using simple command:

```
%load_ext physics
```

This will load the file `~/.ipython/extensions/physics.py`.

How can I tell IPython to load the extension automatically on startup?

I have added the line to `/.ipython/profile_default/startup/import.py`, but that does not work:

```
from numpy import *

%load_ext physics
```

When I start IPython, I get folowing error:

```
File "~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/import.py", line 17
%load_ext physics
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [IPython documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/#using-extensions):

> **Using extensions**
>
> To load an extension while IPython is running, use the `%load_ext` magic:
>
> ```
> In [1]: %load_ext myextension
> ```
>
> To load it each time IPython starts, list it in your configuration file:
>
> ```
> c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = [
>     'myextension'
> ]
> ```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 7):

```
$ cat ~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/load_extensions.py
get_ipython().run_line_magic('load_ext', 'autoreload')
```

Answer (score 4):

I confirm that what you attempted originally, but with an `.ipy` startup file also works:

`~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/physics.ipy`:

```
%load_ext physics
```